# Namespace for Response.Cookies.Append() in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, cookies, openid-connect

I need to use the below code, to set expiration date for my session cookie

```
Response.Cookies.Append(
        OpenIdConnectAuthenticationDefaults.CookieNoncePrefix + Options.StringDataFormat.Protect(nonce),
        NonceProperty,
        new CookieOptions
        {
            HttpOnly = true,
            Secure = Request.IsHttps,
            Expires = DateTime.UtcNow + Options.ProtocolValidator.NonceLifetime
        });
```

Can someone help me to find out the namespace for Response.Cookies.Append()? I tried using the namespace, System.Web and System.Web.HTTP .

I have got the above code from the below link

http://katanaproject.codeplex.com/workitem/402

Thanks in advance

Dinesh

Answer (score 0):

Namespace: System.Web.Mvc

The Response will be property exists in your Controller.

```
public HttpResponseBase Response { get; }
```

Comment: Added the System.Web.Mvc , and my code in controller, but still facing the issue. Following is the namespace i use in my controller

    'using System.Web;
    using System.Web.Mvc;
    using Microsoft.Owin.Security;
    using Microsoft.Owin.Security.Cookies;
    using Microsoft.Owin.Security.OpenIdConnect;'

Answer (score 0):

It is actually part of ControllerBase (which is what Controller inherits from. So if you put the code in  action method in a controller, it will work.

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    [HttpPost]
    public IActionResult MyActionMethod()
    {
        Response.Cookies.Append(
        OpenIdConnectAuthenticationDefaults.CookieNoncePrefix + Options.StringDataFormat.Protect(nonce),
        NonceProperty,
        new CookieOptions
        {
            HttpOnly = true,
            Secure = Request.IsHttps,
            Expires = DateTime.UtcNow + Options.ProtocolValidator.NonceLifetime
        });

        return View();
    }
}
```

Comment: Added my code in controller in a action method, but still same issue.

Comment: Following are my namespace in controller 

' using System.Web;
    using System.Web.Mvc;
    using Microsoft.Owin.Security;
    using Microsoft.Owin.Security.Cookies;
    using Microsoft.Owin.Security.OpenIdConnect;'

Comment: what is the exact error message that appears to you?